# load javascript before refreshing the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, google-maps

here is my code in HTML:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initMap&v=quarterly" defer></script>
<script src="{% static '/javascript/maplanguage.js' %}"></script>


       <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
            <select id="sel_id" name="language" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
            {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
            <option class="option" value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %} >
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select>

    </form>
```

this is aimed to make Django internationalization(change the language of my webpages).

Now I want to change the language of my Google map api **at the same time**.

I have tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Zenoo0/atce2jko/).my code:

```
#maplanguage.js

document.getElementById('sel_id').addEventListener('change', () => {
        let lang = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
//        console.log(lang);
//        alert("You have selected the language code: " + lang);
```

but the problem is :
when I choose one option from the dropdown list, the page will be refresh imediately.
and then I couldnot get the value of "lang" in JS. [which means 'alert' could work before refreshing pages, however there is nothing about the 'console.log'.

So how could I let my pages wait for my JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your HTML, your form submits every time a selection is changed. The submission of the form means the whole page will refresh, so even if you have changed the google map language, it will be lost after the page refreshes. (unless you store that somewhere first).

There are a couple of ways to tackle this:

1. you should let the page refreshes and set a global value via Django at the head script and use that to set the language of the Google map.

i.e.

```js
<script>
var lang = {% currentLang %}
</script>
```

2. submit the form after you set the lang to local storage (or cookie). Then when page has refreshed, grab the `lang` from local storage and passed it to google maps.
   Note below it's a bit of pseudocode, need to verify the form still submits in that function.

i.e.

```js
<script>
function onSelectChange() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('sel_id');
  var langValue = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
  localStorage.setItem('lang', langValue);
  this.form.submit();
}
</script>
```

```html
<select onchange="onSelectChange">...
```

to get a value from localstorage using a key

```js
<script>
var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang');
</script>
```

Comment: **use that to set the language of the Google map**, how could I do that? since I have tried ```<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&language="+lang+"&callback=initMap&v=quarterly" defer></script>``` there is an error in 'lang'

Comment: and also I get ```Invalid block tag on line 12: 'currentLang'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?``` when I add ```<script>var lang = {% currentLang %};</script>``` to my 'base.html'. how could I solve it?

Comment: you will need to use Django's templating braces to insert the language code there.

Comment: I am not familiar with Django (this is a server language), but the idea is to use that to determine the language from the server side and insert into the script tag. So something like: `...&language={% language %}&...`

Comment: for your invalid block issue, my code is only shown as an example. You will need to have a way to get the language code from the server and assign it to something like currentLang.